# Drag and drop a hyperlink from one website (web page) to another

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I would like to add drag and drop functionality not just within a web page. The user would drag a hyperlink from a given web page and drop it into an area of another page. This page would then process the hyperlink on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can get dropped item like that

```
$(document).bind('drop', function (e) {
    var url = $(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')).filter('img').attr('src');
    if (url) {
        jQuery('<img/>', {
            src: url,
            alt: "resim"
        }).appendTo('#imgSection');            
    }
    return false;
})
```